# What's the 0x4000000 sigaction flag on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

It seems that regardless of how I fill `struct sigaction` for the set call to the sigaction function, the `.sa_flags` member gets ORed with
`0x4000000`, or at least that's how I get it if I later retrieve the dispositon with `sigaction(Signum, NULL, &sa)`.

The manpage for sigaction lists the following ORable values for `.sa_flags`:

```
SA_NOCLDSTOP
SA_NOCLDWAIT
SA_NODEFER
SA_ONSTACK
SA_RESETHAND
SA_RESTART
SA_SIGINFO
```

`0x4000000` ANDs to 0 with each of the above. What is `0x4000000`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a `0`? `SA_NODEFER` is 0x4000000`

Comment: In `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/signal.h`/`/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h:` I see: `#define SA_RESTORER     0x04000000`

Comment: That's probably it. That's an obsolete flag, so other include files have it commented out.

Comment: @alk Thanks! Can finally stringify the struct in full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150097/whats-the-0x4000000-sigaction-flag-on-linux/41150297#comment69502710_41150097), from [this man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rt_sigaction.2.html) we learn:

> **SA_RESTORER**
>
> *Not intended for application use*.  This flag is used by C
>                     libraries to indicate that the *sa_restorer* field contains
>                     the address of a "signal trampoline".  See [`sigreturn(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html)
>                     for more details.